# Sending message to a Handler on a dead thread Error while calling Mysql connection

Tags: java, android, android-intentservice

i have called a method which is connecting to Mysql for uploading data and getting this error. I tried new Thread also but no benefit. I read many similar questions mostly related to Toast a message. Can u advice how to handle it. Method is called onHandleintent of class extending to IntentService.

Here is my code:

```
public class LocalService extends IntentService {


    public LocalService() {
        super("LocalService");
    }

    double sal;
    double var;
    int deviceid = 20;


    private String datepattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat(datepattern).format(new Date());
    String timepat = "hh-mm-ss aa";
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat(timepat).format(new Date());

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    uploadtoserver();
                }
            }).start();

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It solved. I created public void onStart(){} and put entire code there leaving onHandleIntent method blank.